# Java Try-Catch Exception Calculator

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to make a user input calculator using *try-catch* and *exception*. The program keeps on repeating and couldn't get the actual input for the numbers and it also includes the statement `Wrong input. Please try again`.

Any idea on how to fix this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=1;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Menu");
                System.out.println("1-Addition");
                System.out.println("2-Subtraction");
                System.out.println("3-Multiplication");
                System.out.println("4-Divison");
                System.out.println("5-Modulos");
                System.out.println("6-Exit");
                System.out.println("Choose option: ");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                int choice = scan.nextInt();  


                switch (choice) {
                    case 1: 
                        System.out.print("Input two numbers:");
                        String dimension = scan.nextLine();
                                String[] parts = dimension.split(" ");
                                int a = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                                int b = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                                int c=a+b;
                                System.out.println("Sum = " +c);
                            break;  
                    case 2: 
                        System.out.print("Input two numbers:");
                        String dif = scan.nextLine();
                                String[] difference = dif.split(" ");
                                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(difference[0]);
                                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(difference[1]);
                                    int d=num1-num2;
                                    System.out.println("Difference = " +d);
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        System.out.print("Input two numbers:");
                        String multi = scan.nextLine();
                                String[] product = multi.split(" ");
                                int num3 = Integer.parseInt(product[0]);
                                int num4 = Integer.parseInt(product[1]);
                                int p=num3*num4;
                                System.out.println("Product = " +p);
                        break;  
                    case 4: 
                        System.out.print("Input two numbers:");
                        String div = scan.nextLine();
                                String[] quotient = div.split(" ");
                                int num5 = Integer.parseInt(quotient[0]);
                                int num6 = Integer.parseInt(quotient[1]);
                                int q=num5/num6;
                                System.out.println("Quotient = " +q);
                         break;
                    case 5: 
                        System.out.print("Input two numbers:");
                        String mod = scan.nextLine();
                                String[] modulo = mod.split(" ");
                                int num7 = Integer.parseInt(modulo[0]);
                                int num8 = Integer.parseInt(modulo[1]);
                                int m=num7%num8;
                                System.out.println("Modulos = " +m);
                        break;
                    case 6: 
                        System.out.println("Now exiting program...");
                        break;  
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
            }
        } while (x==1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you fixed the indentation then the error would be easier to spot.

Comment: Start by changing the catch, and printing the exception by adding e.printStackTrace();. Then using the exception information, you can trace line of code, and the specific error you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

because you are reading next input with `readline()`

```
String dimension = scan.nextLine();
```

and `\n` is already present it the stream when you enter your option with `nextInt()` because `nextint()` never reads the `\n` which you leave behind by pressing `Enter` button.

Answer (score 2):

You should add:

```
scan.skip("\n");
```

right after

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
```

Why? Because nextInt() reads next integer from input. And it leaves new line character at the end on the input. It's like:

```
1<enter>
```

After that you invoke `scan.nextLine()` which reads everything up to next new line character. In fact there is 1 new line character in the buffer. And here your nextLine() reads an empty string.

To solve that issue you have to skip buffered new line characters with `scan.skip("\n")`.

EDIT:
in addition, your code doesn't allow you to exit, because you're not changing your `x` variable. Try to change it after `System.out.println("Now exiting program...");`. It will work ;)

Comment: It still doesn't get me to input two numbers and I couldn't exit it either

Comment: I have entered two numbers and it worked well. And you're unable to exit because you have another bug in the code - you don't change your x variable ;)

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was in the do while method. Thank you for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to identify root cause:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```